# Untyped Actors (Java+Akka): requeuing unhandled messages

Tags: java, akka, actor

I'm creating a system of actors using Java+Akka.
In particular, I define untyped actors by providing an implementation of the onReceive() method.

In that method, I implement the behavior of the actor by defining the logic to be executed upon reception of a message. It may be something as:

```
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
  if(msg instanceof MsgType1){ ... }
  else if(msg instanceof MsgType2){ ... }
  else unhandled(msg);
}
```

However, what if the actor is interested in only a single type of msg?
Is it possible to implement a selective receive, so that the actor waits for a certain msg (and the system automatically re-queues all the other types of messages)???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "a la Erlang" message processing mode is not available in Akka AFAIK. However, you can use [Stash](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/java/untyped-actors.html#Stash) to obtain the effect you want.

So the code would look like this

```
public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if(msg instanceof MsgType1){ ... }
    else if(msg instanceof MsgType2){ ... }
    else stash();
}
```

At some point in the message handling you would switch to another state (presumably by calling `getContext().become`). You would also do a `unstashAll()` call in order to re-append the messages you ignored until that point back to the mailbox.